# store data of different types using listboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

i have a file which has  three types of data the first is type of metal second being a colour and the thrid being quantity of colour , but the number of times they appear in the text file changes (last two types of data),

```
     led, black, 0.50, blue, 0.75, green, 0.60 
     copper,blue, 0.48, red, 0.88, pink, 0.33
     steel, red, 0.65, black, 0.55
     iron, white, 0.5
     copper, black, 1, red, 0.80
     steel, red, 0.62, yellow, 0.50
     copper, blue, 0.48
```

I need a stream reader to read this data in and store it in an appropriate data structure. which then can be used in different parts of my application in WPF, for example the metal type will be placed in one listbox and the other two will be placed in another list box.

```
     StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead("paint.txt"));
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {

            string[] items = line.Split(',');
            cat1 = (items[2]);
            string path = null;
            ;

            string[] led = new string[items.Length];
            string[] copper = new string[items.Length];


            for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
            {
                led[i] = items[i];
                copper[j] = items[i]


                foreach (string paint in items)
                {
                    if (paint.StartsWith("led")) /// paint
                    {
                        path = paint;
                        led[i] = paint;

                    }

                    if (paint.StartsWith("copper")) /// paint
                    {
                        path = paint;
                        led[i] = paint;

                    }
                }

            }

        }

}
```

what i've done so far

Comment: why don't you for starters, show us what you have tried on your own.. second of all you can store the values in a `List<object>` for testing by creating an instance of that for example 
`var myTypes = new List<object>(){ string, string, double, Color, douuble, string, double}`

Comment: Use separate `List<T> objects` as `ListBox.ItemsSource`, see `https://wpf.2000things.com/` for good tutorials.

Comment: I think main problem here is to classify data in different lists of metal, double and colour and not just to load them into a single list or ItemsSource

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straight forward. Read a file in stream reader. Split stream with commas and create a list of strings out of it. Apply following filter methods to classify data in Metal, Color and Double. Here, I have used reference of System.Drawing to check the colour name.

```
private void ClassifyData()
        {
            double dblValue = 0;
            foreach (var item in RandomData)
            {
                if (double.TryParse(item, out dblValue))
                {
                    dblList.Add(dblValue);
                }
                else if (CheckColor(item))
                {
                    ColorList.Add(item);
                }
                else
                {
                    MetalList.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }

        private bool CheckColor(string colorName)
        {
            Color c = Color.FromName(colorName);
            if (c.IsKnownColor)
                return true;
            return false;
        }
```